# Assigning a deferenced variable to a reference variable

Tags: c++

Say if I have the following pointer to a `vector`:

```
vector<int> *v = new vector<int>(10);
```

What is the difference between:

```
vector<int> &vr = *v;
```

and

```
vector<int> vr2 = *v;
```

From my understanding of references, changes to `vr` and `vr2` will not affect `v`. For example:

```
vr.at(0) = 5; 
vr2[1] = 6;
// v[0] and v[1] would not change to 5 and 6 respectively.
```

So what would the difference between `vr` and `vr2` be?

Comment: Have you tried this? What was output?

Comment: As the answers below state, your understanding is wrong. I'm guessing that you've misunderstand the fact that you cannot modify a reference (i.e. you cannot make it refer to something else) to mean that you cannot use a reference to modify what it refers to. That latter statement is wrong.

Comment: And it should be `(*v)[0]` and `(*v)[1]`, not `v[0]` and `v[1]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> From my understanding of references, changes to vr and vr2 will not affect v. For example:

That's an incorrect understanding.

`vr` is a reference to the object that `v` points to. Any changes to `vr` will change the contents of the object that `v` points to.

`vr2`, on the other hand, is a copy. Any changes made to `vr2` affect only `vr2`, not the object that `v` points to.

Answer (score 1):

In the first snippet

```
vector<int> &vr = *v;
```

you declare a **reference** to the vector `v*` points to. Operations on `vr` and `*v` will now have the identical results - that's the essence of references. Here, however

```
vector<int> vr2 = *v;
```

you create a new vector `v2` by **copy assignment**. The new vector holds the same data `*v` holds at the moment of assigning. They are two independent objects now, and changing one doesn't affect the other.